# Swift-tvOS dismissing UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am doing app for `tvOS` and I have problem with canceling `UIAlertController`. I am presenting a `UIAlertController` on top of a normal `UIViewController`. When I push Menu button on tv remote to dismiss the alert, the parent view controller is dismissed first and when i press menu button for the second time, `UIAlertController` disappeared correctly, but after the parent view controller, which i don't want to dismiss.

```
func showTextDescription(message:String?) {
    let allertController=UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    // Cancel action (is invisible, but enables escape)
    allertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: nil, style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(allertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How can i dismiss only `alertcontroller`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call this line of code when you want to dismiss the alert controller.

```
allertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Or you can add an alert action.

```
let alertAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
allertController.addAction(alertAction)
```

Comment: It does not work because, i have no button in `alertcontroller`, where I can add action which close the `allertcontroller`.

Comment: It works, but if i don't want a button in `allertcontroller` exist some way how to do that?

Comment: How do you want to dismiss the alert controller if there isn't any button?

Comment: on tvos is button on remote control ;)

Comment: You can consider using UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel as your style and put nil to your title.